# C compilation errors

Tags: c

I have to write a program in C which calculates and displays the following expression:

`P=1*2*(1/3)*4*5*(1/6)`

I tried running this code ( this is the whole code) but I cant compile it because it shows errors in the fourth and eleventh row in C++..What am I doing wrong?

```
   #include <stdio.h>

    int i,n,f=1;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        if(i%3==0)
           f=f/i;
        else
           f=f*i;
    }
    printf("%d\n", f);
    return 0;
```

I cant write here the erros because they are soooo many..

Comment: where is main() ??????

Comment: Atleast put some of the errors!

Comment: now it shows : parameter f is initialized,syntax error before "for"

Comment: [Please](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to declare `f` as `float`, I am not getting any error in the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i,n;
    float f = 1;
    printf("Enter value of n:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        if(i%3==0)
            f=f/i;
        else
            f=f*i;
    }
    printf("%f\n", f);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The value of n has to be given by the user!

Comment: Ok, you can take it using `scanf`. that's not a big deal.

Comment: There is some error in your code.For every n that i put i get 138.27

Comment: copy it correctly. its giving different value for different input. 138.27 is for 10.

Answer (score 4):

You are missing a definition of the `main()` function. Also, `n` is uninitialized; you need to assign it a value.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i,n,f=1;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        if(i%3==0)
            f=f/i;
        else
            f=f*i;
    }
    printf("%d\n", f);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: n is uninitialized.:)

Comment: Well, that is also true. :)

Comment: +1 for using a semicolon properly and not abusing commas instead.

Comment: This doesnt work.I think that I may have logical errors..

Comment: Yes, start by making sure `n` has a sensible value.

Comment: But I have already done that?

Comment: Well, you must have other errors, then. Update your question with your  latest code, and tell us what the latest errors are.

Comment: No, no, no. Stack Overflow is not a crowd-sourced debugger.

Comment: @user2310758 get a good book and start reading it. You won't learn programming by typing random stuff on a file and then running to ask others to fix it.

Comment: What is the best c programming language book out there in your opinion so I can buy it? I really want to learn man.